# Firebase Anonymous Auth (Android): Lifetime?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm thinking about using anonymous login in one of my apps as I don't really need to know anything about the user and using the account across devices is not required.
However, the user has to provide some information (once when first using the app) in order to use the app. This information is - obviously - linked to the user account. And of course the user should not have to enter this information more than once ever.

My question: What is the "lifetime" of the anonymous account? In which situation will there be a logout / creation of a new anonymous account?
E.g. after restarting the phone, will the user still be logged in with the same account as before the restart?

Thanks for your help!

PS: I only care about Android (and potentially also iOS) - but not web!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the "lifetime" of the anonymous account?

An anonymous user looses his account if the option to log-out is available or if the user uninstalls the app. So you can use Firebase anonymous aAuthentication to create and use **only** temporary anonymous accounts to authenticate with Firebase. As I said, anonymous authentication accounts do **not** persist across application uninstalls. When an application is uninstalled, everything that was saved locally will be deleted, including the anonymous auth token that identifies that account. Unfortunatelly, there is no way to reclaim that token for the user.

If you need more details for your users, you should encourage them to fully log in with a supported account provider (`Google`, `Fabcebook`, `Twitter` and so on) so that they can log in from all their devices without worry of losing their data.

> In which situation will there be a logout / creation of a new anonymous account?

Only if you want that user to create another anonymous account.

> after restarting the phone, will the user still be logged in with the same account as before the restart?

Definetely!

Comment: Hi Daniel! Can I help you with other informations? If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Alex. That was exactly the information I was looking for. One of the reasons I want to go with anonymous login is to lower the hurdle for the users to use the app. Do you happen to have some experience if anonymous login increases the chance that someone uses an app as compared to social login?

Comment: Good to hear that. Yes, because there are many users out there that do not want to provide personal data but still want to use that app. That's why this anonymous option was created